# Comparing 2 dictionaries in python by lookup

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

I have 2 lists dictionaries that i have created that have "similar" data in them, basically it works like this:

dictionary 1 looks like this:

```
{'category' : category, 'location' : location, 'count' : count}
```

dictionary 2 looks like this:

```
{'category' : category, 'location' : location, 'average' : average, 'create_datetime' : create_datetime}
```

Basically, what i want to do is compare the average value and the count value. The idea overall is that i want to see if the count is greater than the average, if it is, i will do something, otherwise i won't.

How would i go about comparing these 2 values? My initial idea was to just put both of these dictionaries on a mysql table and compare them that way, but this is something that will need to run on a regular basis that i would prefer, if possible, to keep out of a table.

Does anyone have some advice on where to start? Thanks!

Comment: So is your question how to store the data?

Comment: not actually storing it, i want to know if there is a way i can compare them in python rather than putting the data into a database and comparing it that way.

Comment: Oh sure if it is a dict, check this out: http://pastebin.com/JFUsZkZM

Answer (score 1):

```
if dict1['count'] > dict2['average']:
    whatever()
```

Pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that your dictionary lists are of the same size. You can write the following code:

```
for dictionary1, dictionary2 in zip(first_list_of_dicts, second_list_of_dicts):
    if dictionary1['count'] > dictionary2['average']:
         pass #Do something
```

Comment: does each one being a LIST of dictionaries change anything? I figure i would need to do something like

for x in dictionary_1_list:
    count = x['count']

etc.,

but how would i ensure that they are comparing the same categories and locations with each other? Maybe i am just thinking too much with a mysql mindset.

Comment: Also, yes they always contain count and always contain average

Comment: No, it doesn't change very much things, actually you need to iterate over the list, comparing your 'average' and 'count' values.

Comment: Note that using the zip function you can iterate over the first and second list of dictionaries as tuples, each of one containing the first item in the first dictionary and the first item in the second dictionary, then the second....and so on..

Comment: It looks like it is working... sort of. While it is working exactly HOW i want it, it appears to be comparing the wrong values, when i print out the details of each list, it looks like the order is different between the 2. Does that matter? If so, how do i order the list the same?


Also, to add, both lists of dictionaries are the exact same size, as every "category/location" pair has both a count and an average (even if the values for some may be 0) so i think it may just have to do with the way it is ordered.

Comment: Yes, order matters make sure 1st dict in the first list corresponds to the 1st dict in the second list and so on....